# Data is null when trying to make AJAX call via jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Can anyone please shed any light on this one?

I have the below code which is a form submission via AJAX and JSON, but I'm getting `uncaught type error cannot read property 'error' of null` messages in Chrome when I view the script.

I'm totally new to JSON, so maybe I have declared something wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form #form_ajax').hide();
    $('#submit').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var valid = '';
    var required =  ' is required';
    var name = $('form #name').val();
    var email = $('form #email').val();
    var message = $('form #message').val();

    if (name == '' || name.length <= 2) {
        valid = '<p>Your name' + required + '</p>';
    }

    if (!email.match(/^[-a-z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{\'?]+(\.[-a-z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{\'?]+)*@([a-z0-9_][-a-z0-9_]*(\.[-a-z0-9_]+)*\.(aero|arpa|biz|com|coop|edu|gov|info|int|mil|museum|name|net|org|pro|travel|mobi|[a-z][a-z])|([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}))(:[0-9]{1,5})?$/i)) {
        valid += '<p>Your email' + required + '</p>';
    }

    if (message == '' || message.length <= 5) {
     valid += '<p>A message' + required + '</p>';
    }

    if (valid != '') {
        $('form #form_ajax').removeClass().addClass('error').html('<p>Please correct the errors below.</p>' + valid).fadeIn('fast');
    } else {

        $('form #form_ajax').removeClass().addClass('processing').html('Processing…').fadeIn('fast');

        var formData = $('form').serialize();
        submitForm(formData);

    }

    });

});

function submitForm(formData) { 
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'mailer.php',
data: formData,
dataType: 'json',
cache: false,
timeout: 7000,
success: function(data) { 


    $("form #form_ajax").removeClass().addClass((data.error === true) ? "error" : "success")

/////HERE'S WHERE I GET THE UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION ERROR////

        .html(data.msg).fadeIn('fast');


    if ($('form #form_ajax').hasClass('success')) { setTimeout($('form #form_ajax').fadeOut('fast'), 5000);

    }

},

error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 

    $('form #form_ajax').removeClass().addClass('error')
            .html('<p>There was an ' + errorThrown + 'error due to a ' + textStatus + ' condition.</p>').fadeIn('fast');

},

complete: function(XMLHttpRequest, status) { 

    $('form')[0].reset();

}


});
};
```

Comment: Is there some code missing here?

Comment: I'm as lost as @DaveNewton. Where do you actually make the ajax request?

Comment: What is the data that's actually being returned from the service?

Comment: Don't forget to scroll down, the Ajax request is further down the pasted code.

Answer (score 0):

In your mailer.php script, be sure to set the Content-Type as JSON:

```
// Send as JSON
header("Content-Type: application/json", true);
```

Though you are passing valid JSON, jQuery's $.ajax doesn't think so because it's missing the header. jQuery used to be fine without the header, but it was changed in version ~1.4.

If this does not solve your problem, be sure that your script is returning a valid JSON response. You can post the JSON here and I will review or check on http://jsonlint.com/ to validate.

**Whoops..** Looks like I've mis-read your question... What is the JSON data that is being returned?

Comment: No joy! How can I see what JSON is outputting??

Comment: If you are using FireFox, I recommended download FireBug which will show you the AJAX requests made in console: http://getfirebug.com/

If using Chrome, you can use the Developer Toolbar to view the remote requests.

Comment: Here's the interesting part, the message does get sent, but the data = null part is stopping my form getting a 'success' flag to clear the form...

Comment: Do you have an online example of this not working? Be sure that your 'mailer.php' script is returning the content that it is suppose to.

Comment: Now fixed, I simply omitted  dataType: 'json', and it worked. Bizarre.

Comment: That would be an indicator that your 'mailer.php' script was not returning valid JSON w/ the JSON Content-Type.